# Does exist some official document to introduce the gc log?

Tags: elasticsearch

Today there was an indexing slow log,

```
[2020-02-12T15:52:37,418][WARN ][i.i.s.index              ] [node-1] [company/KTngnM6ASD-_KdU0FFAWRA] took[22.7s], took_millis[22703], type[_doc], id[20080943028], routing[], source[{...}]
```

then to check `gc.log` to find out why is so,

```
[2020-02-12T07:52:37.417+0000][22539][safepoint      ] Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0004935 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0001389 seconds
[2020-02-12T07:52:37.586+0000][22539][safepoint      ] Application time: 0.1682439 seconds
[2020-02-12T07:52:37.586+0000][22539][safepoint      ] Entering safepoint region: GenCollectForAllocation
[2020-02-12T07:52:37.586+0000][22539][gc,start       ] GC(315124) Pause Young (Allocation Failure)
[2020-02-12T07:52:37.586+0000][22539][gc,task        ] GC(315124) Using 8 workers of 8 for evacuation
[2020-02-12T07:52:37.641+0000][22539][gc,age         ] GC(315124) Desired survivor size 34865152 bytes, new threshold 3 (max threshold 6)
[2020-02-12T07:52:37.641+0000][22539][gc,age         ] GC(315124) Age table with threshold 3 (max threshold 6)
[2020-02-12T07:52:37.641+0000][22539][gc,age         ] GC(315124) - age   1:   22998672 bytes,   22998672 total
[2020-02-12T07:52:37.641+0000][22539][gc,age         ] GC(315124) - age   2:    4966112 bytes,   27964784 total
[2020-02-12T07:52:37.641+0000][22539][gc,age         ] GC(315124) - age   3:   10219520 bytes,   38184304 total
[2020-02-12T07:52:37.641+0000][22539][gc,age         ] GC(315124) - age   4:    4875304 bytes,   43059608 total
[2020-02-12T07:52:37.641+0000][22539][gc,heap        ] GC(315124) ParNew: 597611K->52614K(613440K)
[2020-02-12T07:52:37.641+0000][22539][gc,heap        ] GC(315124) CMS: 4992477K->4998973K(16095680K)
[2020-02-12T07:52:37.641+0000][22539][gc,metaspace   ] GC(315124) Metaspace: 103488K->103488K(1144832K)
[2020-02-12T07:52:37.641+0000][22539][gc             ] GC(315124) Pause Young (Allocation Failure) 5459M->4933M(16317M) 54.724ms
[2020-02-12T07:52:37.641+0000][22539][gc,cpu         ] GC(315124) User=0.35s Sys=0.00s Real=0.06s
[2020-02-12T07:52:37.641+0000][22539][safepoint      ] Leaving safepoint region
```

it seems gc is ok, but some log do not understand, e.g.

```
Entering safepoint region: Cleanup
Entering safepoint region: RevokeBias
Entering safepoint region: GenCollectForAllocation
```

what are `Cleanup`, `RevokeBias`, `GenCollectForAllocation` meaning? and What `Application time` meaning? why are so different?

```
Application time: 0.1382641 seconds
Application time: 13.2106552 seconds
Application time: 106.3031188 seconds
```

Answer (score 1):

It's funny that you mention some things, but do not provide logs for them. Anyway:

`RevokeBias` is when *revoking of biased locking happens* or when "fat" locks from biased locking are deflated.

`GenCollectForAllocation` - this is the reason why the safepoint was triggered. You can read it as : "generational collector for allocation failure". There are [many more other reasons, FYI](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk13/file/0368f3a073a9/src/hotspot/share/runtime/vmOperations.hpp#l64).

`Cleanup` is whatever safepoint [cleanup tasks are](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk13/file/03468b206457/src/hotspot/share/runtime/safepoint.cpp#l651).

AFAIK, if you want *more* details, you need to enable tracing log level.